# Install feature webconsole in karaf 4.3.10 error needs osgi.http (not sure which jar package)

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, web-console, apache-karaf-feature

It reports that it needs `osgi.http`, but i don't know which jar package it need
Here is the command error

> exec /opt/flexinc/apache-karaf-4.3.10/bin/karaf server
> Feb 04, 2024 5:20:40 PM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
> INFO: Trying to lock /opt/flexinc/apache-karaf-4.3.10/lock
> Feb 04, 2024 5:20:40 PM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
> INFO: Lock acquired
> Feb 04, 2024 5:20:40 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAcquired
> INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
> 17:20:41.413 INFO  [EventAdminConfigurationNotifier] Sending Event Admin notification (configuration successful) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
> 17:20:42.180 INFO  [FeaturesServiceImpl] Adding features: framework/[4.3.10,4.3.10],kar/[4.3.10,4.3.10],service/[4.3.10,4.3.10],config/[4.3.10,4.3.10],diagnostic/[4.3.10,4.3.10],package/[4.3.10,4.3.10],shell/[4.3.10,4.3.10],webconsole/[4.3.10,4.3.10],scr/[4.3.10,4.3.10],feature/[4.3.10,4.3.10],jaas/[4.3.10,4.3.10],deployer/[4.3.10,4.3.10],ssh/[4.3.10,4.3.10],management/[4.3.10,4.3.10],system/[4.3.10,4.3.10],log/[4.3.10,4.3.10],eventadmin/[4.3.10,4.3.10],wrap/[2.6.14,2.6.14],bundle/[4.3.10,4.3.10],instance/[4.3.10,4.3.10]
> org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=webconsole; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.3.10,4.3.10]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=webconsole)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.3.10)(version<=4.3.10))" [caused by: Unable to resolve webconsole/4.3.10: missing requirement [webconsole/4.3.10] osgi.implementation; osgi.implementation=osgi.http; version:Version=1.1.0]
> at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1341)
> at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:433)
> at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:420)
> at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:374)
> at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
> at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:399)
> at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1069)
> at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1004)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecuto`your text`r$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve webconsole/4.3.10: missing requirement [webconsole/4.3.10] osgi.implementation; osgi.implementation=osgi.http; version:Version=1.1.0
> at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1341)
> ... 12 more

And i know `requirement [webconsole/4.3.10] osgi.implementation; osgi.implementation=osgi.http; version:Version=1.1.0` comes from

here's feature webconsole in karaf/system/org/apache/karaf/features/standard/4.3.10/standard-4.3.10-features.xml

```
 <feature name="webconsole" description="Base support of the Karaf WebConsole" version="4.3.10">
        <feature>jaas-boot</feature>
        <config name="org.apache.karaf.webconsole">
realm=karaf
role=admin
        </config>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.metatype/1.2.4</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.console/4.3.10</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.memoryusage/1.0.10</bundle>
        <conditional>
            <condition>instance</condition>
            <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.instance/4.3.10</bundle>
        </conditional>
        <conditional>
            <condition>shell</condition>
            <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.gogo/4.3.10</bundle>
        </conditional>
        <conditional>
            <condition>feature</condition>
            <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.karaf.webconsole/org.apache.karaf.webconsole.features/4.3.10</bundle>
        </conditional>
        <requirement>osgi.implementation;osgi.implementation="osgi.http";version:Version="1.1"</requirement>
    </feature>
```

I have all the bundles in this feature, but I don't know how to add `osgi.http`, i don't know the real package name, so anybody can give me some clues, thank you in advance!
the java environment:  java version `11.0.21 2023-10-17 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been resolved by reordering or adding war in the boot feature,  boot features is in the apache-karaf-4.3.10/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg, featuresBoot = (...other boot features),webconsole/4.3.10,scr/4.3.10
in the no error case
featuresBoot = (...other boot features),war/4.3.10,scr/4.3.10,webconsole/4.3.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).